# How should sub-fascia terminating into a lower roof be secured?

Tags: framing, roof, construction, new-home

There was a pre drywall inspection done and one of the findings was a front gable fascia was not completely secured. The report also stated that this reduces the integrity of the roof and can be the source of movement.

This information was provided to the builder and their fix was to splice in a piece of wood.

My question is does this spliced piece of wood make it secure? I don’t believe it does.

The before picture is the one with the red arrow.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After fix]

Answer (score 1):

The original inspection flag was faulty. As a builder I would've disputed it. The overhang is self-supporting, just as it would be if there was no roof below it.

That is exactly how I've built roofs that land on other roofs for decades. It's done that way because the roofing on the lower plane must pass under the overhang on the upper plane to drain properly. It's completely standard and fine.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. There is no overhang. And what do you mean by landing on another roof?

Comment: What do you mean there is no overhang? There are _two_ right in your photos. One of them comes down on top of the other. Are we looking at the same photos?

Answer (score -1):

That added piece to fix this is a total hack job. You should get the contractor back out to properly replace the whole piece back up to the previous lookout block as outlined by yellow in the picture below.

[image]

Picture Source: Question Above.

Make them responsible for quality work. Point out that a hack job like that does absolutely terrible things for their reputation.

Comment: That was my feelings exactly. But now they are saying the city inspector has okayed their fix and the individual that did the pre drywall inspection is saying this is a reasonable fix. So the builder is trying to stand behind the fix.

Comment: Put pressure on these folks. Let them know that their crap work is fully exposed on the internet.